# Rails class inheritance from String giving undefined local variable/method "ti" for main:Object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing Mike Hartl's Rails Tutorial and in section 4.4.2 "Class Inheritance".  Specifically, when attempting to create a class in the Rails console that inherits from the String class [as per "Listing 4.8"](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#code-word_class) I get the following error when I execute it.

```
irb(main):001:0> class Word < String
#<Class:0x56fc868>: undefined local variable or method `ti' for main:Object
        from (irb):25
        from d:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from d:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from d:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
irb(main):026:0> class Word < String
#<Class:0x54a1178>: undefined local variable or method `asodSrlsW' for main:Object
        from (irb):1
        from d:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from d:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from d:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Even weirder...when I try to execute the same line of code again to create the class, thinking perhaps I just had a typo, I get a slightly different error that makes no sense.  Any guidance on this is most appreciated as I'm baffled.

Comment: Maybe you have something bad with your `~/.irbrc`, just a guess.

Comment: you could try changing its name for a while, the rename it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time I see this kind of behaviour is when I am using a console in an eclipse terminal and close it with ctrl+c. Running the console again in the same terminal produces all kind of craziness.

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.4)
irb(main):001:0> class Word < String
irb(main):002:1> puts 'word test'
irb(main):003:1> end
word test
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> ^C
irb(main):004:0>

$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.4)
irb(main):001:0> class Word < String
NameError: uninitialized constant Stn
        from (irb):5
irb(main):006:0>

# At this point pressing cursor up to repeat last line gives garbled nonsense:
irb(main):006:0> la Wr Stn
```

Only solution is to kill that terminal and start fresh.

Comment: Wow--that is random but spot on. I just closed the terminal tab I had been using for the entire exercise within Aptana Studio 3, opened a new one, and presto.